# SQL Server error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a unique id based on the given input and the count of the table.
However, I am getting the required output but when using it in program it returns a error stating

> SQL Server - An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context
>   where a condition is expected, near ')'

Here is my code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetpaymentCode]
(
@O_SupplierCode     varchar(50) output,
@O_ErrorDesc        varchar(100)output
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare     @Error      int
    declare     @Count      char(10)
    declare     @Qry        nvarchar(4000)
    declare     @QryCondition   nvarchar(1000)


DECLARE @Financial_Year VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @TotalMax VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @YearMax VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @TotalCnt INT
DECLARE @YearCnt INT
DECLARE @BillPrefix VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @BillId VARCHAR(20)
SET @Financial_Year = @O_SupplierCode

SET @BillPrefix = 'P'+SUBSTRING(@Financial_Year,8,2)

PRINT @BillPrefix
TRUNCATE TABLE Tbl_Max
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Query = N'WITH T0 AS
(
SELECT MAX(Payment_Id) TotalMax FROM payment_master WHERE Payment_Id 
)
, T1 AS
(
SELECT MAX(Payment_Id) YearMax FROM payment_master WHERE Payment_id LIKE ''' + @BillPrefix + '%''
)
INSERT INTO Tbl_Max
SELECT * FROM T0 INNER JOIN T1 ON 1 = 1'

PRINT @Query

EXEC sp_executesql  @Query

SELECT @TotalMax = ISNULL(TotalMax,'0'), @YearMax = ISNULL(YearMax,'0') FROM Tbl_Max

IF(@TotalMax != '0')
BEGIN
       SET @TotalCnt = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@TotalMax,6,3)) + 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN  
       SET @TotalCnt = 1
END

IF(@YearMax != '0')
BEGIN
       SET @YearCnt = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@YearMax,4,2)) + 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN  
       SET @YearCnt = 1
END


--PRINT @TotalCnt
--PRINT @YearCnt

SET @BillId = @BillPrefix + replace(str(@YearCnt,2),' ','0') + replace(str(@TotalCnt,3),' ','0')

SELECT @BIllId AS BILL_CODE
end
```

Comment: `SELECT MAX(Payment_Id) TotalMax FROM payment_master WHERE Payment_Id` is not valid.

Comment: thanks . i was testing when there is no value in the db. after your correction it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In CTE command in T0 section you have written incomplete where condition.

```
SELECT MAX(Payment_Id) TotalMax FROM payment_master WHERE Payment_Id =?
```